# Mac pythonw / GUI on Catalina OS anaconda - not working python3+

Tags: python, macos, user-interface, pythonw

I am a linux user and am trying to install a GUI driven python package on a student's computer (https://github.com/DeepLabCut/DeepLabCut).

I've exhausted my Mac knowledge after trying many different steps.

1. installed conda + pytonn 3.7 (+ package in question).
2. started up "pythonw" but only python 2.7 version is loading.
3. pythonw is hardlinked to python2.7 in the /usr/bin/pythonw location.  I tried sudo rm -rf but I wasn't allowed to (even with super user). I also read this is a bad idea.
4. tried following installations here (https://docs.python.org/3/using/mac.html) but "pythonw" still linked to mac OS original installation of python2.7. For the life of me I can't seem to find the pythonw3.0.3 installation (from link above) executable even in the anaconda environment directory.

I have already gotten the package above to work on another student's Mac that has an older OS so I know it's not a Mac-specific issue.  Rather, it is an OS issue or something related to changes that I don't understand.

How do I install or load pythonw (the one with graphics/GUI capabilities) that uses python3 native packages?

Thanks so much,

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your PATH environment variable to include where your python 3 is installed.

1.) First verify that you're using the native python install by typing `which pythonw` in terminal (same for python)

2.) Add the path to your python 3 install by typing `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/username/anaconda3/bin/pythonw` (enter your own path)

3.) Re-source your BASH shell to update changes `source $HOME/.bash_profile`

4.) Now type `which pythonw` and the path should now be updated...if not, try next suggestion.

OR

1.) Open your bash profile using `vim $HOME/.bash_profile`

2.) Add `export PATH=/Users/username/anaconda3/bin/pythonw` (don't forget to save)

3.) Re-source your BASH shell to update changes `source $HOME/.bash_profile`

4.) `which pythonw`